# Google Speech API using PHP "Invalid audio channel count" using myfile.FLAC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I use audio32KHz.flac default to test then it's ok. But I try my file FLAC, 32KHz, It not working:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\ApiCore\ApiException: 
{ 
"message": "Invalid audio channel count", 
"code": 3, 
"status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
"details": [] 
} 
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\speech\speech-19\vendor\google\gax\src\ApiException.php on line 139
```

How to convert file my file.FLAC to mono FLAC? Thank you!

Comment: my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTnlICPXiexSNdDeYWfrm86Bps_e0ki3/view

Comment: How many channels do you have in your FLAC source?  What are the config parameters you are sending to the GCP service.  You didn't say if this was speech to text or text to speech.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll change my chanels to 1. In Github, I have the best anwser: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/1006

Comment: I think that the link that you are referring on the previous comment is also explained on the answer from Ksign. Could you please accept his answer so the community can easily find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## 1. To convert your audio file to mono:

You can use the sox library (Easy to install and use)

```
sudo apt-get install -y sox
```

Then convert your file to mono:

```
sox yourfile.flac output.flac channels 1
```

## 2. To use the API with multiple channels audio files:

a). Add these two arguments to your config. I don't know php but I believe you would write it like this:

```
->setaudioChannelCount(2)
->setenableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel(true)
```

Reference: [Transcribing audio with multiple channels](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/multi-channel)

b). Use the gcloud alpha command:

```
gcloud alpha ml speech recognize yourfile.flac --language-code='en-US' --audio-channel-count=2 --separate-channel-recognition
```

Reference: [gcloud alpha ml speech recognize](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/ml/speech/recognize#--audio-channel-count)